# Weird Label behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, label

I add a label to my form like this

```
l = new Label();
l.Location = new Point(520, 94);
l.Size = new Size(95, 20);
l.Text = "Pooling interval (s):";
f.Controls.Add(l);
```

If the text of the label is **"Pooling interval (s):"** the displayed text on the form will only be **"Pooling interval"** but if i change the text too **"Pooling interval(s):"** removing the second space the text gets printed correctly.

Any reason for this to be happening? There is also no overlap of other controls.

Comment: Maybe the width of 95 is too small to display the last part and the entire word "(s)" gets dropped.

Comment: problem in your label size please check

Comment: @Vajura check my answer, i provide the reason and also a code to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the row with size like that:

```
l = new Label();
l.Location = new Point(520, 94);
//l.Size = new Size(95, 20);
l.Text = "Pooling interval (s):";
f.Controls.Add(l);
```

Answer (score -1):

your text is bigger than your label size. so you can use a bigger label, or change AutoSize property to true. try below code.

```
l = new Label();
l.Location = new Point(520, 94);
l.Size = new Size(95, 20);
l.AutoSize = true; // fixes the problem
l.Text = "Pooling interval (s):";
Controls.Add(l);
```